# Unable to subscribe to Mono<XXX> spring webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

i'm trying to write a simple code which takes some date and process it, using reactive elasticsearch
this is the code snippet -

```
            Mono<LastSuccessTime> lastSuccessTime = getLastSuccessTimeMono(brand);

        lastSuccessTime.subscribe(x -> {
            String lastTime = x.getLastSuccessTime();
            log.info("*******test********** : " + lastTime);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String lastTimeStr = formatter.format(LocalDateTime.parse(lastTime, formatter).minusSeconds(10));
            Flux<Player> savedPlayers = savePlayersFromDbService.savePlayersFromSpecificBrand(brand, lastTimeStr);
            log.debug(":migrateForBrand: saved players for brand = " + brand + " are = " + savedPlayers);
        });
```

lastSuccessTime contains '1970-01-01' and i'm trying to print it out, but it seems like it does not do it, cannot see what i'm missing

thanks for the help!

Comment: what is `getLastSuccessTimeMono` because you are probably getting Zero from it. Please post your FULL code and not just a snippet

Comment: If this is all you are running, the buffer of the logger might not be put to the file/console in time before the program is exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a mistake in your code:
in subscribe your creating a flux but doing nothing with it
if you want to get all savedPayers you should subscribe the flux and then print every element.
you can do it like that.
Flux is with lazy evaluation so if your not subscribing it you will not receive any result.

```
  Mono<LastSuccessTime> lastSuccessTime = getLastSuccessTimeMono(brand);

    lastSuccessTime.flatMapMany(x -> {
        String lastTime = x.getLastSuccessTime();
        log.info("*******test********** : " + lastTime);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String lastTimeStr = formatter.format(LocalDateTime.parse(lastTime, formatter).minusSeconds(10));
        Flux<Player> savedPlayers = savePlayersFromDbService.savePlayersFromSpecificBrand(brand, lastTimeStr);
        return savedPlayers;
    })
    .collectList()
    .subscribe(players ->             log.debug(":migrateForBrand: saved players for brand = " + brand + " are = " + players));
```